# Как найти свойства `iblock_property_id` которые отсутствуют в этой таблице?

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Есть таблица, содержащая свойства, `iblock_element_property`.

`id`- уникальный номер
`iblock_property_id` - id свойства
`iblock_element_id` - ид товара
`value` -значение св-ва

Как найти `iblock_element_id`, у которых свойства `iblock_property_id=654`, которые отсутствуют в этой таблице?
Вот картинка правильных данных. `iblock_element_id` =1 это товар,`iblock_element_id` =2 это торговое предложение,
Они содержат набор одинаковых свойств-артикул. (Свойство `iblock_property_id`=654 для товара и `iblock_property_id`=718 Торгового предложения, значения VALUE этих св-в должны быть всегда, и равны между собой. У торгового предложения есть свойство привязки к товару `iblock_property_id`=712)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее, вот это картинка неправильных данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вкратце артикул у торгового предложения есть, у товара нет- поэтому его надо добавить товару.Вопрос-как?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что *которые отсутствуют в этой таблице* , означает, что такого id нет?

Comment: @splash58,да,правильно понимаете, но есть iblock_element_id

Comment: Чтобы найти то, чего нет, надо чтоб оно сначала появилось.

Comment: В смысле?  и как запросом можно сделать?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите заполнять артикул торгового предложения артикулом товара?

Comment: наоборот, артикул торгового предложения записался, а артикул товара не записался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

База выглядит, как [Entity–attribute–value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), поэтому предположу, что есть таблица вроде `iblock_element`, которая содержит все "сущности" (товары и торговые предложения), на которые ссылается `iblock_element_id`. Если нет, то ее можно заменить на `SELECT DISTINCT iblock_element_id FROM iblock_element_property` (предполагается, что у товара есть еще свойства, кроме артикула).

Проблема состоит из двух частей: сначала нам нужно выбрать все товары, у которых нет свойства **654**, затем нужно найти соответствующие им торговые предложения.

```
SELECT 654, goods.iblock_element_id, ep_offer_article.value
  FROM 
         ( iblock_element goods
        LEFT JOIN iblock_element_property ep_goods
          ON goods.iblock_element_id = ep_goods.iblock_element_id
            AND ep_goods.iblock_property_id = 654
         )
    JOIN 
         ( iblock_element offers
        JOIN iblock_element_property ep_offer_goods_link
          ON offers.iblock_element_id = ep_offer_goods_link.iblock_element_id
            AND ep_offer_goods_link.iblock_property_id = 712
        JOIN iblock_element_property ep_offer_article 
          ON offers.iblock_element_id = ep_offer_article.iblock_element_id
            AND ep_offer_article.iblock_property_id = 718
         )
      ON ep_offer_goods_link.value = goods.iblock_element_id
  WHERE ep_goods.iblock_property_id IS NULL -- не задано свойство 654
```

Первая группа `JOIN` в списке таблиц выбирает сущности и свойство 654 (которого может не быть, поэтому использован `LEFT JOIN`), вторая - сущности со свойством-ссылкой на товар (712) и артикулом (718) (все эти свойства должны присутствовать), после чего все пересекается по совпадению товара и ссылки на него. Условие в `WHERE` оставляет в выдаче только товары без артикула.

[INSERT .. SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) допишите сами.

Пример на sqlfiddle.com: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c68e/7

Comment: Спасибо за знания!!!!1